# How to make \ref display only subsection

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I am using the revtex4 package and wanted to change the section numbers to arabic for all levels. Furthermore, I wanted the sections to be displayed as 1.2. (as opposed to 2. only).

I only use sections and subsections, so I did the following:

```
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

Now the sections and subsections are displayed how I want them. However, referencing subsections is now broken. It displays like this (**edited example**):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,pre,floats,aps,amsmath,amssymb,a4,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\def\thesection     {\arabic{section}}
\def\thesubsection  {\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\subsection{A Subsection}
\label{sub:example}
And then some text.

\section{Second Section}
Let's ref Section \ref{sub:example}.

\end{document}
```

[image: what gets displayed]

... instead of `1.1`.

I see two resolutions, but don't know how to go about any of them:

1. Change the display numbers of sections in a smarter way, OR
2. Change what \ref displays (so that it displays only the subsection
   when subsections are referenced.

How can I achieve any of these, or is there another way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `\label` to some counter like `subsection` is normally constructed as `\p@subsection\thesubsection` . In most cases the "prefix" command `\p@...` doesn't typeset anything and thus the result is the same what is produced by `\the...`. Such "prefix" commands are only used by the standard classes to construct references like 1.a in enumerations when the items there are labeled `1` and the subitem `a`.

The  `revtex4.cls` however is using the `\p@...`commands also for heading counters:

```
\def\thesection       {\Roman{section}}
\def\p@section        {}
\def\thesubsection    {\Alph{subsection}}
\def\p@subsection     {\thesection\,}
\def\thesubsubsection {\arabic{subsubsection}}
\def\p@subsubsection  {\thesection\,\thesubsection\,}
```

So if you change `\thesubsection` as you did you end up with the following:

```
\thesection\,\thesection.\arabic{subsection}
```

In other words you need to also change all the corresponding `\p@...`commands to expand to nothing. I the document preamble place:

```
\makeatletter
\def\p@subsection{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thank you for your extended reply. I did try what you propose, but that didn't help. I extended the example above to make the issue more clear (the "see" in the previous example was due to Dropbox not syncing properly, should have been in the TeX).

Comment: you are missing some basic knowledge here, sorry, could have added that part: Commands that contain `@` in their name can only appear in package or class files. Outside, e.g., in the preamble you need to surround them with `\makeatletter` *command defs* `\makeatother`. So what you defined above is really the command `\p` that has to be followed by the string `@section`which is not the same thing. I updated my answer to include this.

Comment: True, I am not very knowledgeable with Latex, but I guess that's what you get by only learning by example.. Thank you very much for your help!