# How to get "full path" of a reference, when \thesubsection do not contain \thesection?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

## Context

My document has following structure:

```
1. First section
   a. Lorem
   b. Ipsum
2. Second section
```

Note that `\thesubsection` is defined *without including `\thesection`*. Or in other words, subsection numbering do not include their parent-section number (i.e. it is *"b. Ipsum"* and not *"1.b. Ipsum"*).

That's great, because I want it like this.

## Problem

Say I create a label in subsection Ipsum.
When I refer to it, **I get *"b."*.**
However, **I would like to get *"1.b."***, i.e. the subsection's reference plus its parent's too.

## Question

How to get the "full reference" of a subsection, when `\thesubsection` do not include section's number?

---

## MWE

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}
\begin{document}
  \section{First section}
    \subsection{Lorem}
    \subsection{Ipsum}
      \label{sec:ipsum}
  \section{Second section}
    The subsection titled "Ipsum" is Subsection \ref{sec:ipsum}.
    However, I would like it to be referred to as "Subsection 1.b".
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\makeatletter 
  \def\p@subsection{\thesection.}
  \makeatother`. I think this is aleardy asked here.

Comment: @touhami This indeed solves my question, thank you. I'm quite sure too, that I am not the first one to ask this question… yet I haven't found the duplicate by myself (as I'm not quite sure the terms of what I was asking). I'd be happy to close/forward my question towards a more relevant one, though!

Comment: @touhami I guess [How to make \ref display only subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61445/64454) details it, yet I think "future-me" would still prefer an answer containing you code snippet (-;